# a refreshing weekend

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

I watched an English education YouTube clip, and a native speaker in the clip said the following:

1. I had a refreshing weekend. (Wrong)
2. I feel refreshed after the weekend. (Correct)

*Source: https://youtu.be/j0lcKGbH8NQ

However, I've found some native speakers say #1.
What do you think? Do you agree with the native speaker in the above clip?
I'd appreciate any feedback.

Comment: Please include a link to the video clip so we can see the full context. While that sentence sounds grammatically correct, it may not apply to a given situation.

Comment: _Refreshing_ usually describes a drink, or food such as juicy fruit, that makes you feel instantly refreshed.

Comment: @KateBunting - I wouldn't have any objection to hearing an experience or person described as 'refreshing' meaning 'a welcome change from e.g. dull routine or the people one usually meets'. My mother was apt to use it sarcastically - she once called a girlfriend of mine 'refreshing', meaning that she was a naive Pollyanna-ish type.

Comment: I just added the link to the clip. ^.^

Answer (score 0):

It is a marginally odd thing to say.  "Refreshing" is normally applied to things like showers or drinks, not to "weekends".  If someone described their weekend as "refreshing", I would want to know more - why did they use that particular choice of words instead of the more common "relaxing", for example?

So it's not wrong, but it is marked - use if it is precisely the right word to describe your weekend. Use it if you want to start a conversation, not just use a generic pleasantry.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed explanation. :)